# Create a PostgreSQL Hyperscale Citus DB from Azure CLI (not ARC)

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-cli, citus

How do I create a hyperscale PostgreSQL DB from the Azure CLI?

Please note, I am not asking about Arc-enabled Kubernetes clusters.

[The current documentation is for Portal only.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/postgresql/hyperscale/quickstart-create-portal.md)

Is there a way to do this from the Azure CLI?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no option for creating Citus tier db, the "az postgres" CLI commands seems to support only the single server and flexible server db creations , as seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/postgres/db?view=azure-cli-latest#az-postgres-db-create)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Furkan is here from Microsoft (PostgreSQL Hyperscale Citus team),

We currently do not support the Azure CLI based provisioning. However, we have rest APIs in private preview. You can see the API description here https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/tree/main/specification/postgresqlhsc/resource-manager

Comment: Thanks for the reply Furkan! Do you know when CLI based provisioning might become available?